# SSH on Mac to fresh install of Firefox on 64-bit CentOS 6.4 runs but generates errors: RANDR and GLib-GIO-WARNING

Tags: ssh, unix, firefox, x11

I just installed (64 bit) Firefox 18 browser on my Linux CentOS 6.4 server (64 bit). I SSH into the server from my Mac OSX Snow Leopard from X11 application using `# ssh -Y mydomain.com`. Now that the Mac is connected to the server, I run firefox on the server by typing in the X11 terminal on my Mac, `# firefox&`.

While firefox is forwarded to my Mac, and appears to run OK, the following errors are reported in the X11 terminal it was opened with:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "localhost:10.0".
(firefox:14774): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Failed to execute child process "update-mime-database" (No such file or directory)
[the last error repeats 4 more times]
```

I installed firefox in the server's `/opt` directory as root user. I simply extracted Mozilla's .tar.bz2 file, and did no other setup other than ensure X11 forwarding works (ssh_config file on server). The browser opened to Mozilla's default webpage.

I was not able to find anything applicable to this after a google search. Wondering if anyone knows what these errors mean, what effect they will have, and finally how to remove them.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question to explain better how OS X is involved in the problem you are facing?

Comment: The question was originally posted on ServerFault, which was downvoted and closed and referred to post here because of X11 terminal interfacing with a Mac OS. If it's not server related (e.g. ServerFault) and not Mac related (e.g. here), perhaps you can recommend where I might post next. The question is how to eliminate the error messages I observe when SSH into server from Mac OS.

Comment: I don't say it doesn't belong here. But as it is written it's quite difficult to understand what you are doing, what part happens on Linux and OS X and which error/warning get's thrown when. Can you try to improve the question to make this more easy to understand and request a reopen?

Comment: Modified posting above to make clearer.

Comment: The second error message (`update-mime-database`) looks like something which should be run on the Linux side (as the Mac only provides the display). Did you try to locate the command on your Linux system?

Comment: It is Mac related because the firefox process running on Linux (which in X11 terminology is the x11 _client_) is trying to use an X11 extension (RANDR) which is not present in the version of quartz (which in X11 terminology is the "X11 _server_") that is running on the Mac. As I state in my answer below, later versions have that extension.(edited below to show that) And to be clear, that is a _warning_, not an error. That extension's presence is not mandatory for the x11 client process. That is one artifact of the flexibility of X11: it will sometimes _warn_ you about stuff that is not fatal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first warning on RANDR, try installing a newer version of [xquartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki)

Searching there just now, it looks like randr was added. I can confirm that on my system which is running xquartz 2.7.4 on OS-X 10.7.5:

```
$ xrandr -v
xrandr program version       1.3.5
Server reports RandR version 1.3
$ sw_vers | grep 'ProductVersion:' | grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*'
10.7.5
```

[image]

For the last warning, does "update-mime-database" exist on the system in the user's $PATH?

Comment: Thanks @Tim B, installing and running xquartz on the Mac did remove the RANDR warning observed on the server. When I SSH into server as user and type `echo $PATH` I do not see `update-mime-database` in it. Do you know what this does (I wonder if it's important)? As an aside, any idea why X11 forwarding of Firefox results in Firefox being sooooo very slow?

Comment: As root on server, I searched `find / -iname update-mime-database` and it returned nothing.

Comment: So you don't have that package installed. You can install it or ignore the warning. (it is common to redirect stderr to /dev/null to ignore x11 client warnings like this)